# Getting Object tag value in AWS S3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags

I am using scala to get information about my objects that are in S3 I am intersted in getting each object I have inside S3 Bucket his tag value so far I have accomplished this code to get me information about my objects but did not succeeded in getting its tagging value: I used this code in scala:

```
def retrieveObjectTags(keyName: String): Unit ={

    try {
      println("Listing objects")
      val req: ListObjectsV2Request =
        new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withMaxKeys(2)
      var result: ListObjectsV2Result = null
      do {


        result = client.listObjectsV2(req)
        for (objectSummary <- result.getObjectSummaries) {
          println(
            " - " + objectSummary.getKey + "  " + "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize +
              ")")

          println(objectSummary.getETag)

        }

        println("Next Continuation Token : " + result.getNextContinuationToken)
        req.setContinuationToken(result.getNextContinuationToken)
      } while (result.isTruncated == true);
  }catch {
      case ase: AmazonServiceException => {
        println(
          "Caught an AmazonServiceException, " + "which means your request made it " +
            "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " +
            "for some reason.")
        println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage)
        println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode)
        println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode)
        println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType)
        println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId)
      }

      case ace: AmazonClientException => {
        println(
          "Caught an AmazonClientException, " + "which means the client encountered " +
            "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
            " with S3, " +
            "such as not being able to access the network.")
        println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage)
      }

    }

//    val getTaggingRequest = new GetObjectTaggingRequest(bucketName,keyName)
//    var getTagResult = client.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest)

    //println(getTaggingRequest)
    var tag: Tag = new Tag()
    println("tag name:" + tag.getValue)

  }
```

as for the remarked lines I have encounter a problem with it, what other way I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: What was the "problem" you "encountered"?

Comment: I cannot get object's tag value ...

Comment: Why not? Does something prevent you from getting it?

Comment: Yes the last code of AWS is deprecated... I wonder if there is another way to get it.

Comment: How does it being deprecated make you "unable" to use it?

Comment: I am looking at 1.11.198, it's not deprecated there ...

Comment: Latest (258) version does not deprecate it either.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectTagging-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectTaggingRequest-